# elasticsearch, magento 1.9

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect elastic search extension to Magento 1.9 store locally.
I created docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
    application:
        container_name: application
        build: docker/application
        volumes:
            - ./application:/app

    php:
        container_name: php_1
        build: docker/php
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - ./application:/app
        links:
            - elasticsearch

    mysql:
        container_name: mysql
        build: docker/mysql
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        volumes:
            - ./docker/tmp/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: db
            MYSQL_USER: db
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: db
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: db
    elasticsearch:
        container_name: elasticsearch
        build: docker/elasticsearch
        ports:
            - 9200:9200
            - 9300:9300
        volumes:
          -./docker/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro
        environment:
            ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.3.1
```

My elasticsearch.yml looks like this:

```
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0

discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

discovery.type: single-node
```

After docker-compose up command i can reach localhost:9200 and it returns:

```
{
 "name" : "vzqbiF3",
 "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
 "cluster_uuid" : "E7nRc0WrRKuD78knlR5zTQ",
 "version" : {
   "number" : "6.3.1",
   "build_flavor" : "oss",
   "build_type" : "tar",
   "build_hash" : "eb782d0",
   "build_date" : "2018-06-29T21:59:26.107521Z",
   "build_snapshot" : false,
   "lucene_version" : "7.3.1",
   "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
   "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
 },
 "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I can reach this also from container with elasticsearch. Command:
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200' return the same.

Problem is that i cannot reach this port from my php container. I recieve:

```
root@45a560f027fe:/app# curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

And obviously Magento cannot connet to elasticsearch.

```
2018-07-11T17:11:11+02:00 CRIT (2): Elasticsearch server is not reachable
```

Where is my mistake? Someone, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

This envionment for elasticsearch should help in resolving the issue

```
environment:
          - xpack.security.enabled=false
          - ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
```

But this flag turning off verification of host that its connecting to it. So it's not safe in production. But if you will not expose the ports out of compose file everything should be safe and available between containers

To connect to elasticsearch from inside php container you need to use this url

`http://elasticsearch:9200`

To test that you probably should be able to make

`curl -X GET 'http://elasticsearch:9200'`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It helps a lot.
Right now i can connect to elasticsearch from php docker, but magento still returns 'Elasticsearch server not reachable'.

Comment: Did you change your elasticsearch host in magento configuration? I mean your host which probably was `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` you should change to `elasticsearch`. Maybe also if you not provided that configuration parameter it by default connects to localhost

Comment: You mean in Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Catalog Search->Servers?
I tried:
http://elasticsearch:9200, wiht and without 'http://', with and withoud '/' at the end. Also 'localhost:9200', '127.0.0.1:9200' nothing works...

Comment: I'm not the expert of magento but what was default value. Also where is your magento app set up? in this `php` container or `application` container? Also maybe try this `System > Index Management` and `reindex all`

Comment: Thaks for your help. I finally resolve it. Elasticsearch version was not compatible with supported extension version. I change the extension and elasticsearch for 5.5.3.
More than less thanks again.